# How can a single thread use 200% CPU usage?

Tags: cpu, htop

[image]

From the screenshot above of `htop` output you can see that mysql is apparently using 204% of CPU usage (this is a CentOS server with dual quad-core Intel Xeons).

However only one core (8) is doing much work, and it says 100%.

One of these is presumably incorrect, what's going on here?

Comment: I feel you should look at this link: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/about-single-threaded-versus-multithreaded-databases-performance/2948#2948

Comment: Hmm interesting that InnoDB is multithreaded, I though there probably was some multithreading gong on here to get that figure, but the output of `htop` here is still confusing. Thanks for the link!